# What I want to do is to print different printouts of the form simultaneously from multiple printers using a single print button

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, web-applications, electron, desktop-application

In our web-based application prepared using AspNetCore and VueJs, printing is being done after the form content is filled. However, the information filled in this form is printed from two different printers and separate buttons are clicked for each printing process and the required printer as well as paper size are selected for the document you want to print.

What I want to do is to print different printouts of the form simultaneously from multiple printers using a single print button. I think this may not be possible to do in a web-based application though…I saw examples of desktop applications made by using C#. It might be possible to do this process with ElectronJs encoding, is it?

Is it possible to open the form section of our application with the web view in ElectronJs Desktop form without rewriting the webform and only by using the print process button with the ElectronJs? (also it shall automatically set the printer settings and prepare the paper measurements). If such setting is possible, can printer definitions be made for printers?

I request you to kindly help me with this. Can anyone who have such experience before share information please?

Thank you in advance.